# Ошибка statement expected в модуле

Tags: typescript, angular

Выскакивает ошибка statement expected в модуле, никак не могу понять в чем причина. Кто знает как исправить?

```
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
﻿import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {TreeviewComponent} from "./tree-view/tree.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [TreeviewComponent]
})

export class ComponentsModule {
}
```

Первая строчка, после "**;**":
[image: Скрин]

Comment: [UTF8 BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101684/statement-expected-syntax-error-highlighting-on-first-line-of-js-file-in-phpst)

Comment: @exvayn кодировка файла UTF-8. Ошибку исправил просто вручную переписав первые 3 строки 1 в 1 (не копируя), потому что после автоимпорта висит данная ошибка. Не знаю в чем проблема и почему после автоимпорта появляется данная ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибку исправил просто вручную переписав первые 3 строки 1 в 1 (не копируя), потому что после автоимпорта висит данная ошибка. Не знаю в чем проблема и почему после автоимпорта появляется данная ошибка, но исправляется вручную переписав импорты.